# My program is giving more than one result when it should only give one?

Tags: python

I have written this scissors paper rock game in python, sometimes it works perfectly but other times it prints more than one result. For example it will say that you tied and then also that you won and sometimes it will also say that you lost. This is not dependent on the actual outcome though and it seems completely random, please help!

```
    while True:
import time
print('Scissors ')
time.sleep(1)
print('     paper')
time.sleep(1)
print('         rock!')
choice = input()
if choice not in ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors'):
    print('Invalid Input')
import random
RPS = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']#BOT CHOICE
#TIE
TIE = ['The bot also chose ' + choice, 'It is a tie!', 'TIE!']
#WIN
RWIN = ['The bot chose scissors, but you smashed them with your rock!', 'YOU WIN!', 'Your rock beat the bots scissors']
PWIN = ['The bot chose rock, but you smothered it with your paper', 'YOU WIN!', 'Your paper beat the bots rock']
SWIN = ['The bot chose paper but you cut it to bits!', 'YOU WIN', 'Your scissors beat the bots paper!']
#LOSS
RLOSS = ['The bot chose paper and smotherd your rock :(', 'You loose...', 'Nice try but you lost...better luck next time']
PLOSS = ['The bot chose scissors and chopped your paper to bits :(', 'You loose...', 'Nice try but you lost...better luck next time']
SLOSS = ['The bot chose rock and smashed your scissors :(', 'You loose...', 'Nice try but you lost...better luck next time']

#TIE
if choice ==(random.choice(RPS)):
    print(random.choice(TIE))



#WIN

#ROCK             
if choice =='rock' and (random.choice(RPS)) =='scissors':
    print(random.choice(RWIN))    
#PAPER
if choice =='paper' and (random.choice(RPS)) =='rock':
        print(random.choice(PWIN))
#SCISSORS
if choice =='scissors' and (random.choice(RPS)) =='paper':
        print(random.choice(SWIN))

#LOSS

#ROCK
if choice =='rock' and (random.choice(RPS)) =='paper':
    print(random.choice(RLOSS))        
#PAPER
if choice =='paper' and (random.choice(RPS)) =='scissors':
    print(random.choice(PLOSS))
#SCISSORS
if choice =='scissors' and (random.choice(RPS)) =='rock':
    print(random.choice(SLOSS))

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(' ')
    print('Again? (y/n) ')
    answer = input()
    if answer in ('y', 'n'):
        break
    print('Invalid input')

if answer =='y':
    continue
else:
    print('Goodbye')
    break
```

Comment: Please show us your output in wrong case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run `random.choice(RPS)` multiple times so every time you get a different result which means it can match multiple ifs or none (you want to match a single one).

To fix it add a variable to store the result of `random.choice(RPS)` (once) and use that variable all in your if statements.

Comment: Thanks, it seems so obvious now haha

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from calling `random.choice(RPS)` in each of your checks, i.e. giving different choice in each if statement. Thus sometimes giving multiple outputs. In order to fix the problem, before any checks for the random bot choice, just record it in a variable and the within the ifs compare to that variable.

Example:

```
bot_choice = random.choice(RPS)

if choice == bot_choice:
    print "you have a tie"
```

and just use `bot_choice`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In each of your conditional tests you are making a new random choice for the computer.  More than one conditional is evaluated (once for tie, once for win, once for loss), and you don't return after you have a positive result, so technically you could have *three* answers in some runs too.

Now, you need to do what the other responses have said - store the result of the "bot" for a single run in a variable instead of re-evaluating each time.  However, you should also clean up your conditional logic so that you're not evaluating impossible equalities (elif), and leave the function after you get a positive result.

Answer (score 0):

You keep generating a new random choice with `random.choose()`.

So even though it might have been a tie, after you check if it's a win, you make the bot choose again and then it will produce a new result.

The way to fix this is make one variable that is the bot's choice. And use `elif`s to check for wins and losses agter you check for a tie.